Migrate AWS ECS cluster IPV4 to IPV6
I'm trying to avoid this new cost (public IPv4) in aws for small projects because it will represent a big percentage of the cost.
In my ECS cluster, I use EC2 instances as capacity providers, therefore, I followed this doc to make every new EC2 instance use IPV6 instead of IPV4 -- which worked.
However these instances are not joining the cluster to be a capacity provider, so the services will not run properly. This cluster was working fine with IPV4. I've tried different configurations in the subnets like:

Enable resource name DNS A record on launch
Enable resource name DNS AAAA record on launch
Hostname type: Resource name
Hostname type: IP name
Enable DNS64

Also, my security groups already support inbounds and outbounds for both types (IPV4 / IPV6)
Am I missing something or ECS doesn't support this configuration (at least with EC2)? If that is the case, do you have a suggestion on how I can reduce this IPV4 cost? For instance, could I avoid this cost using ECS with Fargate?
I know that Fargate cost is bigger than EC2, but maybe EC2 + IPV4 could be more expensive than Fargate using IPV6
EDIT 1:
This is my current route table

EDIT 2:
I was able to ping6 www.google.com which means the instance has an internet connection. However, checking the agent log (/var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log) I got the error:
health check [HEAD http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata] failed with error: Head \"http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata\": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:51678: connect: connection refused" module=healthcheck.go


Can you SSH into one of the EC2 instances and verify it has access to the Internet (using something like a curl command)? It sounds like it can't access the ECS API to register itself with the cluster. If you don't have a VPC endpoint in the VPC for the ECS service, then the instances would need Internet access to connect to the ECS API.

You should be able to use the public IPv6 address to SSH into it.

I've come across the same issue, for the same reason (thanks Amazon).
Can't add a comment, but wondering if it could be related to DNS64, as DNS64 requires a NAT Gateway. This would mean AWS' ECS API endpoint is IPv4 only.
Have you tested with a NAT Gateway? Although, the cost of a NAT gateway negates the whole point of this exercise.
EDIT: Looks like this is the case, the ECS API endpoint hasn't got an AAAA record (as per https://repost.aws/questions/QU36yKU_NRQR6aH_IFLcbV5Q/ecs-support-for-ipv6-only).

So, if I could understand your answer, this migration is impossible without the NAT gateway, right? For small project (with a few instances)The nat gateway price is more expensive than the public IPv4. Since you had the same issue as I have, what did do? –

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Yes, that is correct, you need a NAT gateway for DNS64 as the ECS endpoint hasn’t got an AAAA record.
I haven’t done anything yet, apart from reduce the ALB AZs from 3 to 2, which dropped 1 public IP. What you can do is use IPAM insights (for free) to view your public IP utilisation, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/ipam/view-public-ip-insights.html.
